# Why can't I purchase Hjerim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've done the *Blood on the Ice* and *Morning Never Comes* quests and I've helped citizens and stuff but I still can't buy Hjerim.

I have an Xbox 360 so I can't use console commands but my brother's profile that is on the same Xbox got the house! I really need the house, it's perfect for me. Why can't I buy it?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Is the option to purchase the house not available? Is it available but doesn't seem to do anything? Et cetera. This is, unfortunately, a [particularly buggy](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Hjerim) house and you may have to revert to an earlier save.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you become the Thane. You can't buy a house without being the Thane of whatever city each house is located.

A good way to check is ask the current Jarl or leader of the city (or their Steward) if you can buy a house and he'll tell you if you need to do more quests and help out more citizens first.